# Horizontal fence support

Tags: fence

I am building a 6 f fence with horizonal planks. The posts are 8 -10 feet apart (and pressure-treated) and I'll be using redwood planks. Do I need to include any extra support to prevent sagging or warping?

Answer (score 0):

10' is too far apart unless you are using 2 X 12 for he horizontals

Comment: This question is about to be declared a duplicate of [this one](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/98968/building-horizontal-fence-worried-about-sagging). You might consider adding your answer there; when you do, a bit more text would be helpful.